# Force NuGet Package platform

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

I am trying to use a NuGet Package that was created by an in-house team in my DotNet Core 2.0 application.

When I compile I get the following warning:

> Package 'MyInternalPackage 3.0.0.29' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' **instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.** This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

But when I look at the package in Visual Studio's NuGet Package Manager, It shows this:

[image: Dependencies include DotNet Core]

And when I look at the lib folder in the NuGet package, it shows these folders:

- net451
- netcoreapp2.0

**So, how do I force it to use the netcoreapp2.0 library instead of the full Dot Net Framework Library?**

Comment: your package depends on full framework and the .net core runtime. target it with .net standard 2.0. .net standard stuff can only really reference other .net standard stuff.

Comment: @DanielA.White - The package is supposedly a "Multitarget" package that will allow for use in both the full framework and dotnet core.  (That is why it has a dependency on both)

Comment: sure but you aren't building a .net standard version of it. thats what's missing.

Comment: @DanielA.White - Ah so it is a .net standard != dotnet core issue?

Comment: yes. the library you are trying to add _in to_  is a .net standard one, not a .net core one.

Comment: @DanielA.White - OK I will try that out.  Thanks!

Comment: @DanielA.White - That fixed it!  Please post as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you are adding the package to is a .NET Standard one. Your NuGet package doesn't have a target for .NET Standard. You either have to

1. Generate a .NET Standard package (preferred).
2. Change your class library to target .NET Core instead.

Comment: Why is targeting .NET Standard preferred?  (Still coming up to speed on what it means to target .NET Standard.)

Comment: @Vaccano it allows you to use the class library with .net framework, uwp, .net core, xamarin, etc

Comment: So, do you only need .net standard when building a nuget?  Will that get them all?

Comment: think of .net standard as the interfaces and the various .nets as the concrete implementations.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks!

Comment: yes, youll lose out on some features, but not much.